# SQL MS Access join help average not correct

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, average

I am trying to create a query that displays the average attendance by conference when at least one team was in a game.

[Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FI8c.png)
[image]

this is very close to what im looking for

```
SELECT 
    Conference.ConferenceName, 
    AVG(Game.Attendance) AS AVG_ATT
FROM 
    (
    Conference 
    INNER JOIN School ON Conference.[ConferenceID] = School.[ConferenceID]
    )
    INNER JOIN Game ON 
        (
        School.[SchoolID] = Game.[Team1] 
        OR 
        School.[SchoolID] = Game.[Team2]
        )
GROUP BY 
    Conference.ConferenceName;
```

the problem is if a game has 2 teams from the same conference it adds the attendance twice, and should only do it once.

consider 2 games

### game1

```
Team1- Wisconsin    
Conference - BIG10    
Team2 - Michigan    
Conference - BIG10
Attendance - 100,000
```

### game2

```
Team1- Wisconsin    
Conference - BIG10
Team2 - USC
Conference - PAC12
Attendance - 65,000
```

### Results

```
BIG10-correct    82,500  
PAC12            65,000     
BIG10-Actual     88,333
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a distinct list of the games by conference in a derived query, then do your average.

```
SELECT
    ConferenceName,
    AVG(Attendance) AS AVG_ATT
FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        GameID,
        Conference.ConferenceName, 
        Game.Attendance
    FROM 
        (
        Conference 
        INNER JOIN School ON Conference.[ConferenceID] = School.[ConferenceID]
        )
        INNER JOIN Game ON 
            (
            School.[SchoolID] = Game.[Team1] 
            OR 
            School.[SchoolID] = Game.[Team2]
            )
    ) DerivedDistinctGamesAndConferences
GROUP BY 
    ConferenceName;
```

Comment: Also include `DISTINCT GameID`, other wise you may discard games with exact `Attendace` value.

Answer (score 0):

USE `UNION` to discard duplicated first before doing the average

```
SELECT 
    Game.GameID        
    Game.Attendance
    Conference.ConferenceName
FROM 
    (
    Conference 
    INNER JOIN School ON Conference.[ConferenceID] = School.[ConferenceID]
    )
    INNER JOIN Game ON 
        (
        School.[SchoolID] = Game.[Team1]  -- TEAM 1
        )
UNION 
SELECT 
    Game.GameID        
    Game.Attendance
    Conference.ConferenceName
FROM 
    (
    Conference 
    INNER JOIN School ON Conference.[ConferenceID] = School.[ConferenceID]
    )
    INNER JOIN Game ON 
        (
        School.[SchoolID] = Game.[Team2]  -- TEAM 2
        )
```

So you will get `query1 union query2`

```
GameID   Attendance   Conference
  1         100,000      BIG10    <  one row will disapear
  2          80,000      BIG10
  1         100,000      BIG10    <  after union
  2          80,000      PAC12
```

Then you calculate the avergage over this result

Comment: The average over two sums is only coincidentially the same as the overall average.

Comment: @Johanness Sorry dont understand your comment

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure in terms of coding, but conceptually, the fact that you need to aggregate totals "when at least one" team was- as you then say, only ONCE- at a conference, makes me intuit you may need to use some "if...then" clause statements within VBA script to get the specific calculation you want. Right now, the SQL "or" statement isn't enough.